# convert javascript to unityscript

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using javascript to make 2d game.
I hope to migrate the same play method to 3d(unity).
The model/controller are written in javascript,
it needs to be converted to unityscript,
Is there an automation tool to convert javascript to unity script(they are very similar)?

You comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there are no JavaScript to UnityScript conversion tools. Depending on how complicated your code is, you may only have to make small changes however.